# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\....'' when installing create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

[CMD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxDKd.png), and I also tried to open cmd and run as administrator, still same result as follows:

I keyed in

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

when i entered
`npm start`

I have this error:

```sh
C:\Users\Hoi Yee\my-app>npm start

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Hoi Yee\my-app\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Hoi Yee\my-app\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''

C:\Users\Hoi Yee\my-app>
```

how should I install create-react-app on window 10?

Comment: why did you try to do `npm set prefix`?